# Are ColdFusion CFC's very secure when access is remote?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfc

I am using ColdFusion 9 and jQuery.

I am new pretty new to using ColdFusion CFCs via CFAJAXPROXY.  I am curious as to whether my database is at risk and how I might easily patch security holes.

I put this at the top of the page:

```
<cfajaxproxy cfc="brands" jsclassname="jsApp">
```

Here's a CFC that is used after some logs in:

```
<!--- ADD BRAND  --->
<cffunction name="addBrand" access="remote">
    <cfargument name="SiteID" required="true">
    <cfargument name="Brand" required="true">
    <cfscript>
        LOCAL.SiteID = ARGUMENTS.SiteID;
        LOCAL.Brand = trim(left(ARGUMENTS.Brand, 50));
    </cfscript>
    <cfquery name="GetBrands">
        INSERT INTO Brands(SiteID, Brand)
        VALUES      (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#LOCAL.SiteID#">,
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#LOCAL.Brand#">)
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn true>
</cffunction>
```

Here's the jQuery that would post the data to the CFC

```
$("#AddBrand").click(function() {
    NewBrand = $("#NewBrand").attr("value");
    var jro = new jsApp();
    jro.addBrand(NewBrand);
});
```

So, is there a big security hole here?  Should access="remote" be used only for retrieving data?

Comment: instead of two line of cfscript, how about `<cfset>` ? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, access='remote' does not need to be used only for retrieving data, but it does need to be used carefully and with an understanding of the security implications.

The way you have that set right now, anyone would be able to make a call to insert something into your DB (assuming there are no other access controls that we are not seeing). So you probably should be implementing some type of access control to protect this and other functions.

Now I am going to assume that you did not put the word "easily" in your question and I am going to put in the word "practically" instead. When it comes to security, there is rarely an "easy".

So there are several ways you could protect these methods. A lot depends on how you want to do it and what you are doing already.

1. If you are using `<cflogin>` you may be able to add `roles="<Your Admin role name>"` to the function. I have never tried this, but I suspect it would work. (Personally, I do not like this method for several reasons, but it is an option)
2. You can put some sort of authorization code at the top of the function.

`<cfif NOT mySecurityCFC.isAuthorized(COOKIE.CFID,COOKIE.CFTOKEN)><cfreturn /></cfif>`

I don't like this method either.

1. You could use the new `onCFCRequest()` method of App.cfc in ColdFusion 9 to intercept requests and run them through your authorization routine. This is cleaner than option 2. I would say this is the easiest option, and would work effectively, but I, personally like option 4 better.
2. The ColdSpring project has some great tools for automatically creating and working with remote proxy objects that can also incorporate security through Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP). The combination of remote proxies and AOP is extremely powerful and can allow you to create the remote methods without exposing the real underlying objects and to intercept and authorize each request to those methods without having to stich code into every method. In fact, the methods themselves are not even aware they are being secured.

I would choose option 4. It may sound like a daunting and extremely high-level process, and in some ways it is, but it is actually quite a lot easier than you might think to implement. The steps are outlined in the ColdSpring quick start guide. http://www.coldspringframework.org/index.cfm/go/documentation

Comment: That's funny. I just realized the Stack Overflow is taking the liberty of renumbering my list. In the edit screen it is 1,2,3,4 and in display it is 1,2,1,2.

Answer (score 3):

Well... bear in mind that if you have a method that is remotely accessible... *anyone* can call it.  Not just your AJAX code.  The CF server *doesn't know* whether requests are coming from your AJAX proxy or whether they're coming from anyone else just making a remote call.

And given this method does DB inserts, I think you're leaving yourself a bit open here.  But this applies even with read type calls... you need to bear in mind that - by default - anyone can make the remote call and perform that read.

What you really need to do is to put some sort of authentication & authorisation in place, so only sanctioned requests can make the remote calls.  Get the user to establish a session somehow (like logging in), and only accept remote requests from authorised sessions.

Comment: Adam, this was good advice when you offered it last year. I came up with a great security scheme to protect my CFCs.  Again, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are checking that someone is logged in within your Application.cfc file then this is fine. An AJAX request is just like any other request and will go through the Application.cfc first.

You can test this out by placing an abort in onRequestStart() and seeing that nothing gets inserted. It will probably fail silently and not be the most elegant solution but it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way that you can help protect your remotely accessible CFCs from being called by 'un-authorized' applications.

**Use `verifyClient()` or the cffunction attribute `verifyClient="true"`**

The `verifyClient()` method and `verifyClient` attribute ensure that the calling request has included an encrypted security token which Coldfusion generated for your application. That security token is implicitly submitted along with your data when you make a call to your CFC using `<cfajaxproxy>`. If that token were not included in the request, Coldfusion will throw an exception.

```
<cffunction name="myMethod" access="remote">

    <!--- Prevent requests that have not originated from this application --->
    <cfset verifyClient() >

    ...

</cffunction>

<!-- Or --->

<cffunction name="myMethod" access="remote" verifyClient="true">

    ...

<cffunction>
```

** Railo 3.2.x does not support the `verifyClient()` method. You will have to mimic the behavior yourself if want it.

Comment: This method is great if you know that you will always be using cfajaxproxy of other CF Ajax tools. But I think it quickly become a PITA if you want to make remote ajax calls from a non-CF generated call (like a simple jQuery $.ajax() call).

Comment: @Jason - yeah absolutely. If the OP wanted only calls to spawn from his app, then it makes sense, otherwise using verifyClient() wouldn't be the best approach.

Comment: I eventually did implement your the verifyClient() behavior.  Thanks for the great idea.